# Java class copying and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am having some issues withs objects within an array working as one object rather than seperately as intended. For example

```
boardArray = new object[4];
workingBoardArray = new object[4];
boardArray[0] = new board(boardA);
boardArray[1] = new board(boardB);
boardArray[2] = new board(boardC);
boardArray[3] = new board(boardD);
int selectedBoard = selectBoard(boardArray);
workingBoardArray[0] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoardArray[1] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoardArray[2] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoardArray[3] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoard[0].moveUp();
workingBoard[1].moveRight();
workingBoard[2].moveDown();
workingBoard[3].moveLeft();
```

This code creates a set of 4 boards, finds the desired board, copies that board into the working board array and then shifts each working board in a new direction. The problem is that the boards all act together. So if I do moveUp() on workingBoard[0], workingBoard[1] is also moved up. Is there any way around this, I feel like I am missing some fundamental understand or a really silly mistake.

I also tried using a copy constructer like

```
workingBoard[0] = new Board(boardArray[selectedBoard].getBoard);
```

Which retrieves all essential board information and creates a new board with it, but that doesnt seem to affect anything. Any help would be great

Comment: unable to help unless you post the implementation of the board class(if it is indeed one class definition), if it is going to be cast to an interface at least let us see one of the classes that the define the objects that have the executing method in

Comment: Also, please post the code where boardA, boardB etc. are being created

Comment: Are `workingBoardArray` and `workingBoard` the same? If not where do you define and initialise `workingBoard`?

Comment: ..also please show the real code. The code posted does not even compile. (`new object[4];`)

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your Board class? Furthermore, there is no "getBoard" method in an array. What is  a workingBoard? Where is it defined? Have you ever tried the code you post? If so, could you please provide code that compile?

Answer (score 7):

Look at this code:

```
int selectedBoard = selectBoard(boardArray);
workingBoardArray[0] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoardArray[1] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoardArray[2] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
workingBoardArray[3] = boardArray[selectedBoard];
```

That's setting all four array elements to be *references* to the same object. So yes, when you modify that object by calling `moveUp()` or whatever, that change *will* be visible via all the elements in the array.

It sounds like you may want to create a *copy* of the board each time. Depending on what your `board` type (which should be called `Board` to follow naming conventions) does, you may want to just implement `Cloneable` (quite possibly overriding the `clone()` method) or provide some other sort of copying operation.

Are you aware of the difference between a *reference* and an *object* in Java, and that the array only contains references, not objects? (Likewise any variable value will only be a reference rather than on object.) It's *really* important to understand how objects work in Java. For example:

```
 StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
 StringBuilder b = a;
 a.append("Foo");
 System.out.println(b); // Still prints "Foo"
```

Here we've got *one* `StringBuilder` object, even though there are two variables (`a` and `b`) whose values refer to that same object.

Answer (score 1):

> ... copies that board into the working board array and then shifts each working board in a new direction.

Actually you don't copy the board. There is only one board instance which is referenced four times from workingBoardArray. To make copies of the board you have either to implement the clone method or provide a custom copy method.

For example if you implement the clone method you could write:

```
workingBoardArray[0] = boardArray[selectedBoard].clone();
```